# Change tag name based on attribute using jquery and textarea

Tags: jquery, html

i am here again asking question

here is my text from my textarea

```
 <Abstract>
    <Heading>Abstract</Heading>
    <Para TextBreak="No">Some paragraph <Emphasis Type="Italic">q</Emphasis> </Para>

</Abstract>
```

Possible output

```
<Abstract>
    <Heading>Abstract</Heading>
    <P>Some paragraph <i>q</i> </P>
</Abstract>
```

this is the reason of the output

the text are from text area.

i need to change the tag name based on its attribute

all Para tag must be changed to P tag

and all

```
Type="Italic" attribute must be change to <i> tag
```

i searched for a solution

but the solution i found are modifying the html. and not the content of the text area. thank you so much
this is the solution i found but i can't make it work to my problem

```
$(function(){
    $('#switch').bind('click', function(){
        $('p').replaceWith($('<div/>').html($('p').html()));
    });
});
```

here is the sample of what i need. thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/bc6xequ7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try doing it like below. This will not remove your attributes inside tag `<para>` and `type="Italic"`. But it will definitely replace your tags as you want.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
textval = $('textarea').val();
textnewval = textval.replace('Para TextBreak="No"', 'p').replace('/Para', '/p'); 
  
  if(textnewval.indexOf('Italic') >= 0) //If Italic
{
 EmphasisAttr = 'Italic';
  textnewval = textnewval.replace('Emphasis Type="'+EmphasisAttr+'"', 'i').replace('/Emphasis', '/i'); 
}
if(textnewval.indexOf('Bold') >= 0) //If Bold
{
 EmphasisAttr = 'Bold';
  textnewval = textnewval.replace('Emphasis Type="'+EmphasisAttr+'"', 'b').replace('/Emphasis', '/b'); 
}
if(textnewval.indexOf('Underline') >= 0) //If underline
{
 EmphasisAttr = 'Underline';
 textnewval = textnewval.replace('Emphasis Type="'+EmphasisAttr+'"', 'u').replace('/Emphasis', '/u'); 
}
 

  $('textarea').val(textnewval);
  alert($('textarea').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="20" >
  <Abstract>
    <Heading>Abstract</Heading>
    <Para TextBreak="No" >Some paragraph <Emphasis Type="Italic">q</Emphasis><Emphasis Type="Bold">Bold</Emphasis><Emphasis Type="Underline">Underline</Emphasis> </Para>

</Abstract>
</textarea>
```

Let me know if it is not what you expect.

Comment: it doesn't work. it didn't change the tag name of the closing tag.

Comment: You can try adding replace method for end tags like this.  `.replace('/Para', '/p')`

Comment: that works but sometimes. the emphasis tag contains Bold attribute. is there a way to check the attribute of a specific tag then change its tag name?

Comment: Yes, You can make it conditional. Check above edited snippet for the same.

Comment: the code works sir for the first emphasis italic, bold and underline. but is there a way for this to work. despite how many emphasis tag with italic, bold, or underline?